# Any good RSA/DSA chips?

Tags: integrated-circuit, encryption, security

I would like to find a chip that can do public key encryption/decryption, maybe RSA or DSA. Particularly the key needs to be securely stored on chip. Can anyone suggest some choices?

(Update) Since I am thinking of using it only for authentication and key exchange purpose, speed may not be an issue. Any time less than 1 second per encryption/decryption is acceptable. But security is of a high concern. I would want the key won't be read out  <del>no matter how</del> by a normal hacker (who may have access to the device). I am seeing the SHA chip [ATSHA204](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc8740.pdf) quite attracting in terms of security features. Is there a similar RSA/DSA counterpart?

Comment: You have to specify more accurate requirements. Most of the somewhat larger AVR 8-bit microcontrollers (probably ATmega8+, similar PIC, ...) can do RSA encryption and some manufacturers even supply libraries, but they may be a bit slow for your purpose. As it stands, your question is too broad.

Comment: Any AVR/PIC can ensure secure key storage? I am looking for the RSA/DSA counterpart of this SHA chip: ATSHA204

Comment: There are several tamper resistant microcontrollers available, but it's important to remember that it's tamper resistant, not tamper proof (no matter what the manufacturer claims). Even without going to the extremes of de-encapsulating the chip it's often still possible to recover a key using side channel attacks such as timing and differential power analysis just from precise measurements of the chip's normal operation. If your opponents are skilled, motivated, and moderately funded, and have unsupervised access to several copies of your system, they will be able to get the key.

Comment: There may be some interesting information in this question: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/56482/encrypt-sensitive-data-in-eeprom